# How to retrieve all records based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image: DATABASE RECORDS]

I have a table below where each N_ID(i.e 43, 54, 32, 46 and 24) usually has 3 records. But due to some reason, N_ID with "21 and 39" has only one record.

Requirement: Query all the records by excluding C_Type ! = 2 and then Status should be 1.

Query Used:

```
Select A.N_ID, A.C_Type, A.C_File_Type, A.Status 
FROM TABLE A 
where A.Config_Type != 2 
      AND A.Status = 1 
      AND EXISTS (Select 1 
                  from TABLE B 
                  WHERE A.N_ID = B.N_ID Group By B.N_ID, B.C_Type, B.Status 
                  HAVING count(B.Status) > 1
                  )
```

Output:
I'm getting all the records as expected excluding C_Type = 2.

Now question is how do i change the existing query to get additional records for N_ID='21, 39'? Since those records are not retrieved as part of my query.

Table with data which i got from above query except for the record N_ID = 21, 39, those are not retrieved. I want those highlighted records as well.

[image: NEW TABLE]

Comment: Are you sure the output shown is for the query shown? How can it show statuses other than a 1 ? The first query has a filter "AND A.Status = 1 "

Comment: @ Mandar Actually am comparing the same table where NetworkElementID should be same.

Comment: @ Michael Harmon Yes, am getting all the records only for the status =1 excluding Status=2 and Status=4.

Comment: Added a latest table where am not getting records for N_ID = "21" and "39"(Highlighted one) . How to change the query now to get that?

Comment: What happens if you remove the "HAVING count(B.Status) > 1" in the EXISTS query? This would filter out records that, when grouped according to the GROUP BY, result in a NULL status. I don't think it does anything because the GROUP BY already does this.

Comment: Yes Michael, you are right. Now am getting all the records including N_ID =21, 39 after removing HAVING COUNT(B.Status) > 1. That worked :) Thanks a lot......

Comment: I will post this as answer...

Comment: @ Michael I have some doubt in that query. I have posted my new query in bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove the "HAVING count(B.Status) > 1" in the EXISTS query? This would filter out records that, when grouped according to the GROUP BY, result in a NULL status. I don't think it does anything because the GROUP BY already does this.

Comment: --> your query was behaving in a different way if we use that in above scenario(i.e Pls refer the new table which i updated above)

Comment: If i remove "HAVING count(B.Status) > 1" in below query,                                Select A.N_ID, A.C_Type, A.C_File_Type, A.Status FROM TABLE A 
where A.Config_Type != 2  AND A.Status = 1 
     AND EXISTS (Select 1 
                  from TABLE B 
                  WHERE A.N_ID = B.N_ID Group By B.N_ID, B.C_Type, B.Status                  
                  )

Comment: Then highlighted records (i.e 43 and 46) also retrieved as part of above query. Ideally, I don't need those records since my condition should satisfy like (Status value should be 1 and 1 always) . You can see the sample records like 54, 32, 21, 39, 24.

Comment: Let me know how to change the query in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand the purpose of

```
      AND EXISTS (Select 1 
              from TABLE B 
              WHERE A.N_ID = B.N_ID Group By B.N_ID, B.C_Type, B.Status 
              HAVING count(B.Status) > 1
              )
```

in the query because we are checking the outer A's N_ID  in B the same table's N_ID which will exists ever.

So you can just avoid this exists condition and can simply write the query as

```
    Select A.N_ID, A.C_Type, A.C_File_Type, A.Status 
      FROM TABLE A 
       where A.Config_Type != 2 
        AND A.Status = 1
```